# How to do group by on a multiindex in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, multi-index

Below is my dataframe.  I made some transformations to create the category column and dropped the original column it was derived from.  Now I need to do a group-by to remove the dups e.g. `Love` and `Fashion` can be rolled up via a `groupby` sum.

```
df.colunms = array([category, clicks, revenue, date, impressions, size], dtype=object)
df.values=
[[Love 0 0.36823 2013-11-04 380 300x250]
 [Love 183 474.81522 2013-11-04 374242 300x250]
 [Fashion 0 0.19434 2013-11-04 197 300x250]
 [Fashion 9 18.26422 2013-11-04 13363 300x250]]
```

Here is the index that is created when I created the dataframe

```
print df.index
array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
       17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33,
       34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48])
```

I assume I want to drop the index, and create date, and category as a `multiindex` then do a `groupby` sum of the metrics.  How do I do this in pandas dataframe?

```
df.head(15).to_dict()= {'category': {0: 'Love', 1: 'Love', 2: 'Fashion', 3: 'Fashion', 4: 'Hair', 5: 'Movies', 6: 'Movies', 7: 'Health', 8: 'Health', 9: 'Celebs', 10: 'Celebs', 11: 'Travel', 12: 'Weightloss', 13: 'Diet', 14: 'Bags'}, 'impressions': {0: 380, 1: 374242, 2: 197, 3: 13363, 4: 4, 5: 189, 6: 60632, 7: 269, 8: 40189, 9: 138, 10: 66590, 11: 2227, 12: 22668, 13: 21707, 14: 229}, 'date': {0: '2013-11-04', 1: '2013-11-04', 2: '2013-11-04', 3: '2013-11-04', 4: '2013-11-04', 5: '2013-11-04', 6: '2013-11-04', 7: '2013-11-04', 8: '2013-11-04', 9: '2013-11-04', 10: '2013-11-04', 11: '2013-11-04', 12: '2013-11-04', 13: '2013-11-04', 14: '2013-11-04'}, 'cpc_cpm_revenue': {0: 0.36823, 1: 474.81522000000001, 2: 0.19434000000000001, 3: 18.264220000000002, 4: 0.00080000000000000004, 5: 0.23613000000000001, 6: 81.391139999999993, 7: 0.27171000000000001, 8: 51.258200000000002, 9: 0.11536, 10: 83.966859999999997, 11: 3.43248, 12: 31.695889999999999, 13: 28.459320000000002, 14: 0.43524000000000002}, 'clicks': {0: 0, 1: 183, 2: 0, 3: 9, 4: 0, 5: 1, 6: 20, 7: 0, 8: 21, 9: 0, 10: 32, 11: 1, 12: 12, 13: 9, 14: 2}, 'size': {0: '300x250', 1: '300x250', 2: '300x250', 3: '300x250', 4: '300x250', 5: '300x250', 6: '300x250', 7: '300x250', 8: '300x250', 9: '300x250', 10: '300x250', 11: '300x250', 12: '300x250', 13: '300x250', 14: '300x250'}}
```

Python is 2.7 and pandas is 0.7.0 on ubuntu 12.04.  Below is the error I get if I run the below

```
import pandas
print pandas.__version__
df = pandas.DataFrame.from_dict(
    {
     'category': {0: 'Love', 1: 'Love', 2: 'Fashion', 3: 'Fashion', 4: 'Hair', 5: 'Movies', 6: 'Movies', 7: 'Health', 8: 'Health', 9: 'Celebs', 10: 'Celebs', 11: 'Travel', 12: 'Weightloss', 13: 'Diet', 14: 'Bags'}, 
     'impressions': {0: 380, 1: 374242, 2: 197, 3: 13363, 4: 4, 5: 189, 6: 60632, 7: 269, 8: 40189, 9: 138, 10: 66590, 11: 2227, 12: 22668, 13: 21707, 14: 229}, 
     'date': {0: '2013-11-04', 1: '2013-11-04', 2: '2013-11-04', 3: '2013-11-04', 4: '2013-11-04', 5: '2013-11-04', 6: '2013-11-04', 7: '2013-11-04', 8: '2013-11-04', 9: '2013-11-04', 10: '2013-11-04', 11: '2013-11-04', 12: '2013-11-04', 13: '2013-11-04', 14: '2013-11-04'}, 'cpc_cpm_revenue': {0: 0.36823, 1: 474.81522000000001, 2: 0.19434000000000001, 3: 18.264220000000002, 4: 0.00080000000000000004, 5: 0.23613000000000001, 6: 81.391139999999993, 7: 0.27171000000000001, 8: 51.258200000000002, 9: 0.11536, 10: 83.966859999999997, 11: 3.43248, 12: 31.695889999999999, 13: 28.459320000000002, 14: 0.43524000000000002}, 'clicks': {0: 0, 1: 183, 2: 0, 3: 9, 4: 0, 5: 1, 6: 20, 7: 0, 8: 21, 9: 0, 10: 32, 11: 1, 12: 12, 13: 9, 14: 2}, 'size': {0: '300x250', 1: '300x250', 2: '300x250', 3: '300x250', 4: '300x250', 5: '300x250', 6: '300x250', 7: '300x250', 8: '300x250', 9: '300x250', 10: '300x250', 11: '300x250', 12: '300x250', 13: '300x250', 14: '300x250'}
    }
)
df.set_index(['date', 'category'], inplace=True)
df.groupby(level=[0,1]).sum()


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/devops/reports/groupby_sub.py", line 9, in <module>
    df.set_index(['date', 'category'], inplace=True)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/pandas/core/frame.py", line 1927, in set_index
    raise Exception('Index has duplicate keys: %s' % duplicates)
Exception: Index has duplicate keys: [('2013-11-04', 'Celebs'), ('2013-11-04', 'Fashion'), ('2013-11-04', 'Health'), ('2013-11-04', 'Love'), ('2013-11-04', 'Movies')]
```

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You can create the index on the existing dataframe. With the subset of data provided, this works for me:

```
import pandas
df = pandas.DataFrame.from_dict(
    {
     'category': {0: 'Love', 1: 'Love', 2: 'Fashion', 3: 'Fashion', 4: 'Hair', 5: 'Movies', 6: 'Movies', 7: 'Health', 8: 'Health', 9: 'Celebs', 10: 'Celebs', 11: 'Travel', 12: 'Weightloss', 13: 'Diet', 14: 'Bags'}, 
     'impressions': {0: 380, 1: 374242, 2: 197, 3: 13363, 4: 4, 5: 189, 6: 60632, 7: 269, 8: 40189, 9: 138, 10: 66590, 11: 2227, 12: 22668, 13: 21707, 14: 229}, 
     'date': {0: '2013-11-04', 1: '2013-11-04', 2: '2013-11-04', 3: '2013-11-04', 4: '2013-11-04', 5: '2013-11-04', 6: '2013-11-04', 7: '2013-11-04', 8: '2013-11-04', 9: '2013-11-04', 10: '2013-11-04', 11: '2013-11-04', 12: '2013-11-04', 13: '2013-11-04', 14: '2013-11-04'}, 'cpc_cpm_revenue': {0: 0.36823, 1: 474.81522000000001, 2: 0.19434000000000001, 3: 18.264220000000002, 4: 0.00080000000000000004, 5: 0.23613000000000001, 6: 81.391139999999993, 7: 0.27171000000000001, 8: 51.258200000000002, 9: 0.11536, 10: 83.966859999999997, 11: 3.43248, 12: 31.695889999999999, 13: 28.459320000000002, 14: 0.43524000000000002}, 'clicks': {0: 0, 1: 183, 2: 0, 3: 9, 4: 0, 5: 1, 6: 20, 7: 0, 8: 21, 9: 0, 10: 32, 11: 1, 12: 12, 13: 9, 14: 2}, 'size': {0: '300x250', 1: '300x250', 2: '300x250', 3: '300x250', 4: '300x250', 5: '300x250', 6: '300x250', 7: '300x250', 8: '300x250', 9: '300x250', 10: '300x250', 11: '300x250', 12: '300x250', 13: '300x250', 14: '300x250'}
    }
)
df.set_index(['date', 'category'], inplace=True)
df.groupby(level=[0,1]).sum()
```

If you're having duplicate index issues with the full dataset, you'll need to clean up the data a bit. Remove the duplicate rows if that's amenable. If the duplicate rows are valid, then what sets them apart from each other? If you can add that to the dataframe and include it in the index, that's ideal. If not, just create a dummy column that defaults to 1, but can be 2 or 3 or ... `N` in the case of `N` duplicates -- and then include that field in the index as well.

Alternatively, I'm pretty sure you can skip the index creation and directly `groupby` with columns:

`df.groupby(by=['date', 'category']).sum()`

Again, that works on the subset of data that you posted.

Comment: raise Exception('Index has duplicate keys: %s' % duplicates)
Exception: Index has duplicate keys: [('2013-11-04', 'Beauty'), ('2013-11-04', 'Celebs'), ('2013-11-04', 'Diet'), ('2013-11-04', 'Fashion'), ('2013-11-04', 'Health'), ('2013-11-04', 'Inspiration'), ('2013-11-04', 'Lifestyle'), ('2013-11-04', 'Love'), ('2013-11-04', 'Movies'), ('2013-11-04', 'Parenting')]

Comment: @Tampa Looks like you might need to clean up your data a bit. The portion you posted works for me (see my edits).

Comment: this worked...  df.groupby(by=['date', 'category']).sum()   Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I usually try to do it when I try to unstack a multi-index and it fails because there are duplicate values.

Here is the simple command that I run the find the problematic items:

```
df.groupby(level=df.index.names).count()
```

It will probably display some invalid data that you must adjust.

Comment: Only solution that worked for me. Be aware that all of your index levels need to be named in order for this to work. If they aren't already you can set them with `df.index.names = ['foo','bar']`