# groupby in pandas messes with row indexes

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas df with three columns, purchase_day, customer_name, products_purchased.

I want to return an array of number of days that each customer visited the store. So I used

```
gpd = df.groupby(by=['customer_name', 'purchase_day']).count()
```

which returns a table that looks like:
[image]

Unfortunately with this returned table, I can't run groupby on it because of the unusual format (where customer_name and purchase_days aren't in the first row but in the second).

Any tips so that I can count the number of purchase_days each customer visited the store?

Comment: Can you add the actual result as code instead of a drawing on a piece of paper please? I do appreciate the effort :P

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is resetting the index.

Since you apply `.groupby` the dataframe with multiple columns,

the dataframe returned would have a [MultiIndex](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html).

`gpd = df.groupby(by=['customer_name', 'purchase_day']).count().reset_index()`

Also you can still apply `.groupby` with multiindexed dataframe.

In the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) of method `pandas.DataFrame.groupby`,

there is a para `level` which you can use to set multiindices as groupby columns.

There is a SO thread on this that you can check out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19798229/python-pandas-how-to-do-group-by-on-a-multiindex).