# pandas Series groupby with one group

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, series

Input:

```py
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame(data={'date':[pd.Timestamp('2016-02-15')]*3, 
    'time':[pd.Timedelta(x) for x in ('07:30:00','10:10:00','11:10:00')],'name':['A']*3, 'N':[1,2,3]}
).set_index(['date','time','name']).sort_index()
data = data[ data.index.get_level_values('time')>=pd.to_timedelta('09:30:00') ]
dataGB = data['N'].groupby(['date','name'])
print(data)
print('Number of groups:',len(dataGB))
print(dataGB.sum())
print(pd.__version__)
```

Output:

```
>>> print(data)
                          N
date       time     name   
2016-02-15 10:10:00 A     2
           11:10:00 A     3
>>> print('Number of groups:',len(dataGB))
Number of groups: 2
>>> print(dataGB.sum())
date    2
name    3
Name: N, dtype: int64
>>> print(pd.__version__)
0.24.1
```

Questions:

1. Why do I get 2 groups while clearly there should be only one?
2. Why do I get garbage from `dataGB.sum()` and what to do to get expected (below) result?

*Expected* result of `dataGB.sum()`:

```
>>> dataGB.sum()
date        name
2016-02-15  A       5
Name: N, dtype: int64
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: you should access the column you want _after_ the `groupby` --> `data.groupby(['date', 'name'])['N'].sum() `

Comment: Could you please explain why it matters?

Comment: because in this instance you are specifying you want to `sum` on the `N` column which you are not doing when you try and access the column beforehand

Comment: @aws_apprentice If I access the column beforehand, I essentially do `groupby` on a `pd.Series`, while if do it after, I select the column on which the subsequent operation should be applied. It is not clear to me why the former way to do it is incorrect: it seems that the results should be identical.

Comment: I think this is a bug with multiindex and grouping on index labels for pd.Series.groupby.  This statement works if you use double brackets around 'N' and covert it to a dataframe instead of a series.

Comment: Also, this statement works if you group by using the `level` paramenter instead of index level names.

Comment: @ScottBoston According to [Grouping DataFrame with Index Levels and Columns](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#grouping-dataframe-with-index-levels-and-columns) : *Index level names may be specified as keys directly to groupby* (starting with version 0.20). So, what I did should be correct.

Comment: I agree, this maybe a bug with pd.Series.groupby that is not present in pd.DataFrame.groupby.  Note: when you use data[['N']] vs data['N'] it works as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be a bug with `pd.Series.groupby`, I will submit a bug report in pandas for this case.

Work Around #1 use a pd.DataFrame instead of pd.Series

```
data[['N']].groupby(['date','name']).sum()
```

Output:

```
                 N
date       name   
2016-02-15 A     5
```

Work Around #2 use the level parameter in groupby

```
data['N'].groupby(level=[0,2]).sum()
```

Output:

```
date        name
2016-02-15  A       5
Name: N, dtype: int64
```

Work Around #3 use a dataframe with an aggregator column:

```
 data.groupby(['date', 'name'])['N'].sum()
```

Output:

```
date        name
2016-02-15  A       5
Name: N, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Work Around #3 was point out above in comments by @aws_apprentice, i.e. `data.groupby(['date', 'name'])['N'].sum()`

Comment: Yes, workaround #3 is using a dataframe also.   Thanks I will add this to the solution.

Comment: I did not see a corresponding potential bug submission on pandas github, so I have just submitted one: [Pontential bug in Series groupby #25704](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/25704)

Answer (score 1):

According to this post, [Python Pandas - how to do group by on a multiindex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19798229/python-pandas-how-to-do-group-by-on-a-multiindex), grouping on a multiindex should be done like this

```
dataGB = data['N'].groupby(level=[0,2])
```