# Group by columns while merging data frames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I am merging several data frames into one data frame in a for loop. something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.randint(0,100,(2,5)),columns=list('ABCDE'))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.randint(0,100,(2,5)),columns=list('GHABC'))
df1 = df1.merge(df2, how='outer', left_index=True, right_index=True,suffixes=('', '_' + 'second'))
```

Several columns from each of these data frames have similar names so each time there is such a column I am adding a suffix. It is becoming a mess. In addition, I would like to be able to quickly access all the columns from the first table, second one, etc. Is there a way to merge these columns but keep them as a group? So that I don't need to change the column name and I can access all the columns of each data set easier?

Comment: You could add a column `data_source` for each dataframe and join them vertically.

Comment: This is a good idea to be able to quickly access where they come from, but I still need to change the column names if there is a duplicated name. True?

Comment: Not if you join them vertically, instead of horizontally as you do now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to merge the dataframes horizonthally with the help of [MultiIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html), which has some advantages comparing to vertical merge. For example, you won't have lots of `NaN` fields, and the dtype's won't change from `int` to `float` like in the case with horizonthal merge.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.randint(0, 100, (2, 5)),
                   columns=list('ABCDE'))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.randint(0, 100, (2, 5)),
                   columns=list('GHABC'))
dfs = [df1, df2]
result = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1, keys=range(len(dfs)))
print(result)
```

This will give:

```
    0                   1                
    A   B   C   D   E   G   H   A   B   C
0  41  49  13  36  57  28  12  82  18  67
1  72  91  34  17  12   6  67  98  36  25
```

You can access each group in a loop:

```
for source_index, df in result.groupby(axis=1, level=0):
    print(df)
```

```
    0                
    A   B   C   D   E
0  41  49  13  36  57
1  72  91  34  17  12
    1                
    G   H   A   B   C
0  28  12  82  18  67
1   6  67  98  36  25
```

or individually:

```
gb = result.groupby(axis=1, level=0)
first_group = gb.get_group(0)
print(first_group)
```

```
    0                
    A   B   C   D   E
0  41  49  13  36  57
1  72  91  34  17  12
```

---

References:

- [Concatenate pandas columns under new multi-index level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23600582/concatenate-pandas-columns-under-new-multi-index-level)
- [How to do group by on a multiindex in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19798229/python-pandas-how-to-do-group-by-on-a-multiindex)
- [How to access pandas groupby dataframe by key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14734533/how-to-access-pandas-groupby-dataframe-by-key)

Comment: Thanks Georgy, this is exactly what I was searching for!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an illustration of what @QuangHoang proposed in their [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55903528/group-by-columns-while-merging-data-frames#comment98462843_55903528):

```
import pandas as pd


df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.randint(0, 100, (2, 5)),
                   columns=list('ABCDE'))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.randint(0, 100, (2, 5)),
                   columns=list('GHABC'))
dfs = [df1, df2]
for source_index, df in enumerate(dfs):
    df['data_source'] = source_index
result = pd.concat(dfs)
print(result)
```

will give all your dataframes joined vertically:

```
    A   B   C     D     E     G     H  data_source
0  66  52  16  73.0  59.0   NaN   NaN            0
1  73  64  59  31.0  13.0   NaN   NaN            0
0  72  79  45   NaN   NaN  30.0   0.0            1
1  45  52  40   NaN   NaN   2.0  80.0            1
```

To access each group in a loop you can do:

```
for source_index, df in result.groupby('data_source'):
    print(df.dropna(axis=1))
```

```
    A   B   C     D     E  data_source
0  66  52  16  73.0  59.0            0
1  73  64  59  31.0  13.0            0
    A   B   C     G     H  data_source
0  72  79  45  30.0   0.0            1
1  45  52  40   2.0  80.0            1
```

or [by an index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14734533/how-to-access-pandas-groupby-dataframe-by-key) of the source:

```
gb = result.groupby('data_source')
source_index = 0
first_group = gb.get_group(source_index).dropna(axis=1)
print(first_group)
```

```
    A   B   C     D     E  data_source
0  66  52  16  73.0  59.0            0
1  73  64  59  31.0  13.0            0
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. My data sets are large and the number of columns they have in common is not a lot (compared to the total number of columns). I am not sure If I should create a large data frame with lots of NaN.

Comment: In addition, the columns I am reading are going to be used all for training a model, so still it makes sense to keep them joined horizentally